# Jquery : animate navbar to top on scoll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate my `navbar` to animate to `top: 0` on page scroll. Right now my nav is coming after slider image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() === 100) { // this refers to window
            $('.navbar').animate('top': 0);
        } else {
            $('.navbar').animate('top': 300);
        }
    });
})
```

But this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery animate function is wrong

```
$('.navbar').animate({top: "0px"});
$('.navbar').animate({top: "300px"});
```

In css you need to have position fixed or absolute